# Change Label Text Alignment in App Inventor 2 code block

Tags: app-inventor

I would like to know wether we can change the Text Alignment of a label using the App Inventor 2's Code Block. I would like to make a button to select the text alignment position of a label or button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the text alignment of a label programmatically in App Inventor

As workaround for example define 2 Labels, one having an alignment left and another having an alighment right and hide the second label. Then after button click copy the text of the label and display the other label instead, see screenshot.

[image]